# Tagging when a message is uploaded in Logstash

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I have a large ingestion pipeline, and sometimes it takes awhile for things to progress from source to the Elasticsearch index. Currently, when we parse our messages with Logstash, we parse the `@timestamp` field based on when the message was written by the source. However, due to large volumes of messages, it takes a currently unknown and possibly very inconsistent length of time to travel from the source producer before it's ingested by Logstash and sent to the Elasticsearch index.

Is there a way to add a field to the Elasticsearch output plugin for Logstash that will mark when a message is sent to Elasticsearch?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add a ruby filter as your last filter to create a field with the current time.

```
ruby { 
     code => "event.set('fieldName', Time.now())"
}
```

Comment: Check if '@timestamp' is null and then you can use mutate to update '@timestamp'.

Answer (score -1):

You can do it in an [ingest pipeline](https://gist.github.com/cdahlqvist/e713b39f0c17d85e613f56408a7facd5). That means the script is executed in elasticsearch, so it has the advantage of including any delays caused by back-pressure from the output.